# Finding the longest repetitive piece in a string python

Tags: python, string, function

I want to write a function "longest" where my input doc test looks like this (python)

```
"""
>>>longest('1211')
1
>>>longest('1212')
2
>>>longest('212111212112112121222222212212112121')
2
>>>lvs('1')
0
>>>lvs('121')
0
>>>lvs('12112')
0

"""
```

What I am trying to achieve is that for example in the first case the 1 is repeated in the back with "11" so the repeated part is 1 and this repeated part is 1 character long it is this length that this function should return.

So in the case of the second you got "1212" so the repeated part is "12" which is 2 characters long.

The tricky thing here is that the longest is "2222222" but this doesn't matter since it is not in the front nor the back. The solution for the last doc test is that 21 is being repeated which is 2 characters long.

The code I have created this far is following
import re

```
def repetitions(s):
    r = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
    for match in r.finditer(s):
        yield (match.group(1), len(match.group(0)) / len(match.group(1)))


def longest(s):
    """
    >>> longest('1211')
    1
    """
    nummer_hoeveel_keer = dict(repetitions(s)) #gives a dictionary with as key the number (for doctest 1 this be 1) and as value the length of the key 

    if nummer_hoeveel_keer == {}: #if there are no repetitive nothing should be returnd
        return 0

    sleutels = nummer_hoeveel_keer.keys() #here i collect the keys to see which has has the longest length

    lengtes = {}

    for sleutel in sleutels:
        lengte = len(sleutel)
        lengtes[lengte] = sleutel

    while lengtes != {}: #as long there isn't a match and the list isn't empty i keep looking for the longest repetitive which is or in the beginning or in the back
        maximum_lengte = max(lengtes.keys())

        lengte_sleutel = {v: k for k, v in lengtes.items()}
        x= int(nummer_hoeveel_keer[(lengtes[maximum_lengte])])

        achter  = s[len(s) - maximum_lengte*x:]
        voor = s[:maximum_lengte*x]

        combinatie = lengtes[maximum_lengte]*x

        if achter == combinatie or voor == combinatie:
            return maximum_lengte

        del lengtes[str(maximum_lengte)]
    return 0
```

when following doc test is put in this code

```
"""
longest('12112')
0
""
```

there is a key error where I put "del lengtes[str(maximum_lengte)]"

after a suggestion of @theausome I used his code as a base to work further with (see answer): this makes my code right now look like this:

```
def longest(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return 0
    longest_patt = []
    k = s[-1]
    longest_patt.append(k)
    for c in s[-2::-1]:
        if c != k:
            longest_patt.append(c)
        else:
            break
    rev_l = list(reversed(longest_patt))
    character = ''.join(rev_l)
    length = len(rev_l)
    s = s.replace(' ','')[:-length]
    if s[-length:] == character:
        return len(longest_patt)
    else:
        return 0

l = longest(s)
print l
```

Still there are some doc tests that are troubling me like for example:

```
>>>longest('211211222212121111111')
3 #I get 1

>>>longest('2111222122222221211221222112211')
4 #I get 1
>>>longest('122211222221221112111')
4 #I get 1
>>>longest('121212222112222112')
6 #I get 1
```

Anyone has ideas how to deal with/ approach this problem, maybe find a more graceful way around the problem ?

Comment: This algorithm wont be fast, that for sure. :)

Comment: @andreyF i included it above

Comment: Why do you need something like this?

Comment: @ubdussamad it's an exercise since I am learning to program

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code. It works perfectly for your input doc tests.

```
def longest(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return 0
    longest_patt = []
    k = s[-1]
    longest_patt.append(k)
    for c in s[-2::-1]:
        if c != k:
            longest_patt.append(c)
        else:
            break
    rev_l = list(reversed(longest_patt))
    character = ''.join(rev_l)
    length = len(rev_l)
    s = s.replace(' ','')[:-length]
    if s[-length:] == character:
        return len(longest_patt)
    else:
        return 0

l = longest(s)
print l
```

Output:

```
longest('1211')
1
longest('1212')
2
longest('212111212112112121222222212212112121')
2
longest('1')
0
longest('121')
0
longest('12112')
0
```

Comment: This indeed works for the docs but when putting into the site i use for these exercise (gives over 50 doc tests to run) for example this one fails

""
lvs('12112')
0
"""

the program above gives me 3 as solution. So i guess somewhere there is still something wrong, when this example is added (also examples  like 1 fail simple because 1 isn't repetitive yet the program counts 1 with len 1 so returns 1)

Comment: I didn't know they were special before i saw them not fit your code. Sorry for the inconvenient I did add them now

Comment: I've updated the code. Now it works well for all your cases. If you find good, let me know. :)

Comment: This code works for examples given still have some who aren't working I have added then to the doc test, but you couldn't know ofcourse since i did not realize these were special cases. 

As for the code in my class i learned that when you define something you always use return. Why do you use print ? is this for a special reason or a personal choice. Thanks a lot

Comment: When you use `return`, you exit from function with the value you got, so rest of the function does not run. For example: if length of input is `1` means that the result should be `0` anyhow, so return `0` will avoid any further complications.